# How to remove a number enclosed between html tags

Tags: php, regex, string

I have a string, something like below string:

```
$var = 'It is a text<nobr><font color="#176200">﴿3﴾</font></nobr>';
```

Now I want below output:

```
 $var = 'It is a text';
```

**Note:** The number of `3` is changeable.

How can I do that ?

Comment: Is there any logic behind your desire result?

Comment: @Kasra Yes, I want replace this with null : `<nobr><font color="#176200">﴿{any number}﴾</font></nobr>`. Now my problem is that I can't define {any number} in `str_replace();` function.

Comment: You ask for "how to remove a numeber (number) enclosed between html tags" so to get `3` but you actually want `'It is a text`

Comment: The most obvious way is `/^[^<]+/`

Comment: @SuperDJ You right, I want to remove number and tags.

Comment: Sometimes the simple solution is in the blind spot of fear.\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of replacing number and tags with null you can get the first part (the string) with following regex :

```
^[^<]*
```

see [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/uG4uR0/1)

---

**EDIT:**

And then you can replace result of above code in the main string, something like this:

```
$var = 'It is a text<nobr><font color="#176200">﴿3﴾</font></nobr>';
$sec_part = preg_replace('/^[^<]*/','', $var);
$result = str_replace($sec_part,'',$var);
echo $result;
```

output:

```
It is a text
```